# How to use multiple $or in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, where-clause

Im writing a query where i need multiple 'or' statements.

this is my whereClause:

```
{
  date_added: {
    '$lte': '2019-04-18', '$gte': '2019-04-11'
  },
  '$or': [ 
    { id: [Array], secondary_id:[Array] }
  ],
  '$and': [ 
    { third_id: [Array], fourth_id:[Array] }
  ],///make it into $or
}
```

such that there where statements changes from

```
WHERE ("date_added" <= '2019-04-18' AND "date_added" >= '2019-04-11') 
  AND ("id" IN ('10') or "secondary_id" in ('11')) 
  AND ("third_id" IN ('12') and "fourth_id" in ('13'))
```

INTO

```
WHERE ("date_added" <= '2019-04-18' AND "date_added" >= '2019-04-11') 
  AND ("id" IN ('10') or "secondary_id" in ('11')) 
  AND ("third_id" IN ('12') OR "fourth_id" in ('13'))
```

Another way to say it would how could i use sequelize to do (A or B) and (C or D)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [Sequelize operator symbols](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html#operators) and not the string values in your example, they have been deprecated. To recreate the query in your SQL, you would want to do something like the following:

```
const Op = Sequelize.Op

where: {
  date_added: {
    [Op.between]: ['2019-04-18', '2019-04-11'],
  },
  id: {
    [Op.in]: arrayOfIds,
  }
  [Op.or]: [
    {
      channel_type: {
        [Op.like]: {
          [Op.any]: ['facebook', 'instagram'],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

SQL

```
WHERE date_added BETWEEN '2019-04-18' AND '2019-04-11'
  AND id IN (... your id array)
  AND (
    channel_type LIKE 'facebook'
    OR channel_type LIKE 'instagram'
  )
```

Comment: but how to solve (A or B) AND (C or D) in sequelize ?

Comment: @ManishGadhock use `Op.and` and wrap two `Op.or`s.